# Parsing nested JSON in ANDROID

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse this structure: (Its driving me insane and I tried everything I can think of. However I am not very experienced)

```
{
    "topDrops" : {
        "week" : "14",
        "player" : [ {
            "percent" : "3.70",
            "id" : "10948"
        }, {
            "percent" : "3.49",
            "id" : "0532"
        }, {
            "percent" : "2.46",
            "id" : "11214"
        }, {
            "percent" : "2.20",
            "id" : "0529"
        }, {
            "percent" : "2.04",
            "id" : "0508"
        } ]
    },
    "version" : "1.0",
    "encoding" : "ISO-8859-1" 
}
```

The "topDrop" is like a filename? player is a JSONArray that consists of 5 player JSONObjects. But what is the top considerd as in JSON terms. I checkes out valid on the JSON validator I need something like:

topDrop as JSONObject
Player as JSONArray
and the loop through the objects in the array.

any suggestions? 
/ johan

Comment: Do you have some code about what you achieved so far?

Comment: I'll try to get it clean. I've changed it so many times its a mess right now.

Comment: a/ parse the json. b/ topDrops is a jsonobject referred by its name. c/ in this jsonobject, player is a jsonarray, also referred by its name. d/ in this array, there are several jsonobjects. e/ Think of jsonobjects as Maps, or Associative arrays.

Comment: Yes this is true. I got it to work now. I think i got entangled in the loops and lost track of things. Thank you very much everybody for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code for parsing json from an URL :

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONObject jObj;
// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
Log.v("debug", "JSON ready to parsing");
return jObj;
}

public void parsingData(JSONObject json) {
try {
    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        // Do your stuff, example :
        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject topDrops = c.getJSONObject("topDrops");
        JSONArray playerArray = topDrops.getJSONArray("player");
        // playerArray.getJSONObject(0) == first player
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.v("debug", "Error during the connection HTTP");
    cancel(Boolean.TRUE);
}
}
```

Comment: looks prettys much what i have used except I use AsyncHttpClient to get the data. and this works on a "simple" JSON with 1 array of many objects. Its the "top" object that is the problem. I cant seem to get an array "under" a object or 2 objects under eachother. the methods don't support that.

Comment: Have you tried JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i); mySecondArray = c.getJSONArray("player"); ? I edited my answer

Comment: But isn't the "{-symbol" and indication of an object and the "[" indication of an array? it should be object-array-object right?

Comment: I got it to work now. I think i got entangled in the loops and lost track of things. Thank you very much everybody for the input.

Comment: I edited my code to work with your sample. Your welcome, vote up and validate if it helped you :)

Comment: Not allowed to vote up yet (need 15 "points") :( but i validated it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java library called JSONSimple that will do it for you.[link](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: checking ti out right now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help you! :) This's my solution.

```
Integer Week;
String Version, Encoding;
ArrayList<Double> Percent;
ArrayList<Integer> ID;

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(...JSON String...);
JSONObject TopDrops = jObject.getJSONObject("topDrops");
Week = TopDrops.getInt("week");

JSONArray Player = TopDrops.getJSONArray("player");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     Percent.add(Player.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("percent"));
     ID.add(Player.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
}
Version = TopDrops.getString("version");
Encoding = TopDrops.getString("encoding");
```

Link to download full project: [JSONParseProject](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1KYgbqD74EXTlhxNW9VSy1FSW8/edit?usp=sharing)

Can you send url with this JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I always use Gson library from Google : https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
and To generate POJO I use online utilities like this one http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ or this one http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/. After that its a matter of writing one line to generate or parse any json. I have **never** parsed json manually.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have here an object, which contains an object that called `topDrops` inside it you have a string called `week`, and an array called `player`. Each object in this array contains a string called `percent` and a string called `id`. After that you have another two strings `version` and `encoding`.

I won't write you the whole parsing method, but I recommend you to go over this blog post I wrote on this subject, from it you can understand how to parse this object with what android gives you and using the `Gson` library, there is a project there you can download and experiment with.

[JSON Parsing](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)